# Modeler with optional inputs or none?

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, qgis-modeler

I have a need for a model that all the input may be optional and allow the "Selected features only" option.
So, I developed a model that fakes it all as seen in the example below

[image]

I realize that some SAGA algoritms acepts none input, so it can start de process allowing the selected features either. 
I create some regular points to use in the merge, so the next algoritm will always receive something and don´t cause an error.

The question is.
Is this the only and viable solution, or the long way one?
because regardless the input, it takes at least 6 seconds to finish, even empty.

Comment: What parameter is the `Input (Not Mandatory)`? Because the **Vector Features** parameter provides an optional setting for selected features which could be used directly into the `Merge vector layers` tool.

Comment: @Joseph The Input is a shapefile of any kind. If Merge is the first step of de modeler it will ignore the setting for selected features. So, I used the Add Indicator to be sure that only the selected ones will reach the merge.